# Architecture and Infrastructure for Robo-Advisor

Tags: portfolio-management

Does anybody have any knowledge of Architecture and/or Infrastructure needed for building your own Robo Advisor. I am looking for directions to get in-depth  knowledge for building your own Robo Advisor. Any help would be greatly appritiated.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I don't see any relationship with quantitative finance.

Comment: Agreed, algorithms for Robo Advisors could be on-topic but Architecture and/or Infrastructure seems to be focused more on the IT.